# Pandas Ranking for String Columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rank, ranking-functions

I have a sample dataframe like this. Basically I want to do ranking based on item_number and location_id. I could've done something like that in SQL using window function (dense_rank, over() partition by).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_number': [1029980, 1029980, 1029980, 1029980, 1029980, 
                                   1029980, 1029980, 1029980, 1029980, 1029980],
                   'location_id': ['L3-25-AA-05-B', 'L3-25-AA-05-B', 'L3-25-AA-05-B', 'L3-25-AA-05-B', 'L3-25-AA-05-B', 
                                   'L4-25-AA-05-B', 'L4-25-AA-05-B','L4-25-AA-05-B', 'L4-25-AA-05-B', 'L4-25-AA-05-B'],
                   'Date': ['2021-10-01', '2021-10-02', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-04', '2021-10-05', 
                            '2021-10-01', '2021-10-02', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-04', '2021-10-05']})
```

| item_number | location_id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-01 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-02 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-03 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-04 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-05 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-01 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-02 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-03 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-04 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-05 |

I want the data to be like this. The ranking is grouped by item_number and location_id. If the item_number and location_id are same then it's considered in a same group and ranking should be done based on the Date.

| item_number | location_id | Date | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-01 | 5 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-02 | 4 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-03 | 3 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-04 | 2 |
| 1029980 | L3-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-05 | 1 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-01 | 5 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-02 | 4 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-03 | 3 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-04 | 2 |
| 1029980 | L4-25-AA-05-B | 2021-10-05 | 1 |

I have tried this code but it's giving an error as the columns are all string.

```
test['rank'] = test.groupby(['item_number','location_id']).rank()
```

The above code gave me this error.

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Comment: Will you please add the result of `print(df.head().to_dict())`? It works for me.

Comment: Note that you probably want to use `.rank(ascending=False)` instead of `.rank()` (per your expected output)

Comment: {'item_number': {3: 1029980},
 'location_id': {3: 'L3-25-AA-05-B'},
 'Date': {3: '2021-10-05'}} here is the result of print(df.head().to_dict())

Comment: Thank you for editing. I have added your suggested version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case do

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['item_number','location_id'])['Date'].rank(ascending=False)
0    5.0
1    4.0
2    3.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    5.0
6    4.0
7    3.0
8    2.0
9    1.0
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, this one worked. Also, I found few duplicates in my data that's why I could not use groupby earlier. Thanks @BENY

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
test.dtypes
```

to see what type the columns are that you are using (if they are numeric of not) and then potentially use astype: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
test.astype({"item_number": "int"}).groupby(['item_number','location_id']).rank()
```

Though I'm not sure if that would work for location_id.

Comment: You're right. It would work but the problem is location_id won't change. And because of that I cannot use .rank().

Comment: Have you tried using sort_values: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: I would have used sort_values only but I have to partition it by item_number and then by location_id as well. That's where I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can reverse the dataframe, `groupby` on `item_number` and `location_id` and `cumcount` `Date`s:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['item_number','location_id'], as_index=False)['Date'].cumcount(ascending=False)+1
```

Output:

```
   item_number    location_id        Date  rank
0      1029980  L3-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-01     5
1      1029980  L3-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-02     4
2      1029980  L3-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-03     3
3      1029980  L3-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-04     2
4      1029980  L3-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-05     1
5      1029980  L4-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-01     5
6      1029980  L4-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-02     4
7      1029980  L4-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-03     3
8      1029980  L4-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-04     2
9      1029980  L4-25-AA-05-B  2021-10-05     1
```